# qt how to make floating widgets in tab

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator

There is QTabWidget with some tabs and i want to make to user can move widgets in each tab and attach them to any side of tab.

Among the standard widgets this functionality have QToolBar and QDockWidget, but they attach only to QMainWindow.

Is there any widgets that can attach to my widget which inherits QWidget? Or any solutions to make changeable interface?

Thanks.

P.S. My english is terrible, I know.

Answer (score 0):

By default I don't think that's possible.

You can however implement that functionality yourself by for example checking boundaries and when a certain threshold is met you set its x or y to the parent x and or y. Adding an animation would make it seem smoother also.

Another way would be to use a `QMainWindow` instead, so you can use `QDockWidget`.

There's no rule against having multiple `QMainWindow` and they inherit from `QWidget` anyhow which makes them work with for example `QTabWidget::addTab(QWidget *page, const QString &label)`.

How this affects performance would be worth a test.

Comment: Thanks, QMainWindow really can be as a tab of QTabWidget. For myself, I solved this by creating inherited classes from QMainWindow for each tab and adding tabs in a constructor of main form like that: 
`tab0 = new Tab0(this);
    tab1 = new Tab1(this);

    ui->tabWidget->addTab(tab0, "tab0");
    ui->tabWidget->addTab(tab1, "tab1");`